# How to deactivate the camera after clicking the 'Stop Recording' button? (using React.js and react-media-recorder)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, video

When the user enters the page for the first time, they can see the live stream preview. After that, when they click on the start button, they can start recording. After recording, they can stop and deactivate the camera by clicking the stop recording button.

After clicking the 'Stop Recording' button, the camera is still working. I do not want that. i need to deactivate the camera

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import { useReactMediaRecorder } from "react-media-recorder";

const VideoPreview: React.FC<{ stream: MediaStream | null }> = ({ stream }) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(videoRef.current)
    if (videoRef.current) {
      videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
      console.log(videoRef.current.srcObject)
    }

    return () => {
      if (videoRef.current) {
        videoRef.current.srcObject = null; // Release camera stream
      }
    };
  }, [stream]);

  if (!stream) {
    return null;
  }

  return <video ref={videoRef} width={500} height={500} autoPlay controls />;
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl, clearBlobUrl } =
    useReactMediaRecorder({
      video: true,
      onStop: () => {
        console.log("hi i am stop");
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then((stream) => {
          const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
          mediaRecorder.stop();
        });
      },
    });

  const previewStream = useRef<MediaStream | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "idle") {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then((stream) => {
          previewStream.current = stream;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error accessing user media:", error);
        });
    }
  }, [status]);

  const handleReset = () => {
    clearBlobUrl();
  };
  console.log(status);

  return (
    <div className="m-16">
      <>
        {status === "idle" && (
          <button className="bg-yellow-300 mx-5 p-3" onClick={startRecording}>
            Start Recording
          </button>
        )}
        {(status === "recording" || status === "stopped") && (
          <button className="bg-red-400 p-3 mx-5" onClick={stopRecording}>
            Stop Recording
          </button>
        )}
        <button className="bg-lime-500 p-3 mx-5" onClick={handleReset}>
          Reset Recording
        </button>
      </>

      {(status === "idle" || status === "recording") && (
        <VideoPreview stream={previewStream.current} />
      )}
      {mediaBlobUrl && (
        <video src={mediaBlobUrl} className="m-5 w-88" controls autoPlay />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried this way but no use still error.

```
onStop: () => {
        // Stop the camera when recording stops
        if (previewStream.current) {
          previewStream.current.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
            track.stop();
          });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to stop the camera stream after recording stops by accessing the `previewStream.current` directly in the **onStop** callback. However, there is a logical error in your code. The onStop callback provided by **useReactMediaRecorder** is called after the recording stops, not when you stop the camera.

Therefore, accessing the `previewStream.current` won't give you the current camera stream since it's a reference to the preview stream, not the recording stream.

**Solution:**

To stop the camera stream after recording stops, you should handle this logic inside the stopRecording function. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl, clearBlobUrl } =
    useReactMediaRecorder({
      video: true,
      onStop: () => {
        // This function is called after recording stops
        console.log("Recording stopped");
      },
    });

  const previewStream = useRef<MediaStream | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "idle") {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then((stream) => {
          previewStream.current = stream;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error accessing user media:", error);
        });
    }
  }, [status]);

  const handleReset = () => {
    clearBlobUrl();
  };

  const handleStopRecording = () => {
    if (previewStream.current) {
      previewStream.current.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        track.stop();
      });
    }
    stopRecording(); // Call stopRecording after stopping the camera stream
  };

  return (
    <div className="m-16">
      <>
        {status === "idle" && (
          <button className="bg-yellow-300 mx-5 p-3" onClick={startRecording}>
            Start Recording
          </button>
        )}
        {(status === "recording" || status === "stopped") && (
          <button className="bg-red-400 p-3 mx-5" onClick={handleStopRecording}>
            Stop Recording
          </button>
        )}
        <button className="bg-lime-500 p-3 mx-5" onClick={handleReset}>
          Reset Recording
        </button>
      </>

      {(status === "idle" || status === "recording") && (
        <VideoPreview stream={previewStream.current} />
      )}
      {mediaBlobUrl && (
        <video src={mediaBlobUrl} className="m-5 w-88" controls autoPlay />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In this modified version, I've introduced a new function **handleStopRecording** which stops the camera stream using `previewStream.current.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop())` and then calls `stopRecording()`.

This ensures that the camera stream is stopped after recording stops.